# Proving $\lim_{x\to c} g\circ f(x)= g(b)$ without sequential criterion

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, continuity

Pardon my English beforehand. I want to prove, without using the sequential criterion for continuity, the next theorem:

> Let $f$,$g$ be defined on $\mathbb R$ and let $c\in \mathbb R$. Suppose $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=b$ and that $g$ is continuous at $b$. Show that $$\lim_{x\to c} g\circ f(x)= g(b)$$

It is known that for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $x\in \mathbb R$, $$0<|x-c|<\delta \implies |f(x)-b|<\varepsilon$$

It is also known by continuity of $g$ at $b$ that for all $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $\delta '>0$ such that for all $x\in \mathbb R$, $$|x-b|<\delta ' \implies |g(x)-g(b)|<\varepsilon $$

I have a weak approach to this. Using the continuity of $g$ on $b$ we know for $f(x)\in \mathbb R$ that $$|f(x)-b|<\delta ' \implies |gf((x))-g(b)|<\varepsilon $$

This is where I don't know if I'm correct. Using the limit of $f$ and letting $\varepsilon := \delta '$ then $$0<|x-c|<\delta \implies |f(x)-b|<\delta ' \implies |gf((x))-g(b)|<\varepsilon $$ which implies

$$0<|x-c|<\delta \implies |gf((x))-g(b)|<\varepsilon $$

Is my idea correct? If so, how can I write a formal proof? I get confused when writing the "for all epsilon there exists delta" segment of the definition to finally say that $\lim_{x\to c} g\circ  f(x)= g(b)$. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can't set $\epsilon$.

Comment: I thought that, because the definition of limit works for every $\varepsilon >0$, in particular it could work with $\varepsilon :=\delta '>0$. So it's incorrect?

Comment: Uhm, I would say so. It is correct that in particular it could work for $e:=\delta^{\prime}$(and it should), but that is insufficient. You have to find a $\delta$ for *every* $\epsilon$.